# Login screen ios5 freeze

Tags: iphone, ios, authentication

I have a login screen set up from the app delegate like this:

```
  NSUserDefaults *def = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
BOOL needsPassCheck = [def boolForKey:kHasPassword];
if (needsPassCheck) {
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle: nil];

    VerifyPasswordViewController *passC = (VerifyPasswordViewController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"passCheck"];
    passC.loginCheck = YES;
    self.window.rootViewController = passC;
}
```

In the view controller the start up methods are:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    if (self.loginCheck) {
        [self.topBar setHidden:YES];
        self.enterPLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Enter Password", @"Enter Password");
    }else {
        [self.topBar setHidden:NO];
        self.enterPLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Enter Old Password", @"Enter Old Password");
    }

    [self.continueButton setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Continue", @"Continue") forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 }

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    [self.passwordTextField becomeFirstResponder];

    [self viewDidAppear:animated];

}
```

The problems is that it seems to go in a infinite loop: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fws6m.png

What is the problem? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, its obvous, you have recursive in your code. In each viewDidAppear you call another viewDidAppear.
Instead of:

```
[self viewDidAppear:animated];
```

call:

```
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
```

Comment: There is another problem... the text field becomes first responder only after the view is displayed as I did above .. when I use a segue to get to this view the keyboard does not show